# Interpreting JavaScript security scan warning

Tags: javascript, authentication, vbscript

Running Acunetix on my website shows the severe vulnerability below

URL encoded GET input username was set to " onmouseover=prompt(994492) bad="
The input is reflected inside a tag element between double quotes.

I have tried to figure out what could be done with this. I am fairly new to coding and am looking for some tips. What could be entered as a username that would be considered malicious? Wouldn't any code entered only be run on the client PC and not the server?

Examples? Solutions? Sorry, I just included what I believe it is referencing. Wouldn't it be bad to link to my site if it is in danger of being exploited?

```
<form name="loginForm" action="LoginName.asp" method="post">
      <fieldset>
      <label for="username">User</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password"/>

      </fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" name="originalURL" value="">
      <input type="submit" value="Login" class="form-btn" />
</form>
```

It appears to not like the username or OriginalURL and says that "Malicious users may inject JavaScript, VBScript, ActiveX, HTML or Flash into a vulnerable application to fool a user in order to gather data from them. An attacker can steal the session cookie and take over the account, impersonating the user. It is also possible to modify the content of the page presented to the user."

Comment: Please quote the markup that it's complaining about.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a link to the site and/or an example of the relevant section of HTML.

Comment: @dgvid: The relevant markup must be in the question, not just linked. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quoted the markup, but at a guess I'd say you have a poorly-formed `input` tag for your "username" input. For instance, perhaps it's missing the closing `"` on the `value` attribute, and the text you see quoted is what follows it.

> Wouldn't any code entered only be run on the client PC and not the server?

That depends entirely on what you do with it. If you pass it to something else that interprets it (for instance, a database interpreting SQL), then you'll be open to attack that way. That particular kind of attack is called an SQL Injection attack ([article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) | [cartoon](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

Answer (score 0):

Anything that could replace your SQL code (search for SQL Injection). Things that might get written to the screen as output HTML. You can control both cases by escaping your input data.

Comment: I have looked into it and have been unable to get anything to properly execute. I am assuming this is just a false positive.

Comment: Could be. But never hurts to look into stuff where security might be compromised. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look up cross sight scripting, javascript injection, and sql injection for some exploits to your system.

All user input should be verified and treated as untrusted data before forwarding to your server.

Comment: We would need more info for an exact assesment as to your vulnerability.

Comment: What other info would be helpful?